# How to resolve error Cannot resolve 'ListenableFuture' after adding com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

After adding com.google.gms:google-services below, I am getting an error that ListenableFuture cannot be found.

I'm using a method in a class in androidx.camera.lifecycle, which returns a ListenableFuture, so I'm guessing 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' and "androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}" are using conflicting versions of ListenableFuture.

How do I best resolve this?

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.0.2'

    def camerax_version = "1.2.0-alpha02"

    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}"

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be late to the party here but I had the same issue and there seems to be some conflicting references to the ListenableFuture class. Solved this by adding a "direct" reference to Kotlinx Coroutines Guava in gradle (app):

```
implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-guava:1.6.2")
```

This seems to solve the conflict by saying "use ListenableFuture from this dependency" ish. Hopefully this works for you as well!